# What does GO mean in "go to sleep"?

Tags: word-meaning

What does *go* mean in *go to sleep*? Does it mean *to start* as in *here we go*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means *fall asleep*.

> I went to sleep almost as soon as I climbed into bed.

> 12. [to proceed towards an activity](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/go)
>     *to go to **supper***
>     *to go to **sleep***

Answer (score 2):

It is an example of a common metaphor: JOURNEY -> CHANGE of STATE

Other examples are

> Go to pieces (fail, or become distressed)

> Come to understand something

> Reach a conclusion

> Go mad/crazy